# Angular 7 lazy loaded module's component loading twice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, lazy-loading, angular7-router

I made a very cut down version of our project here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-double-load-issue

We have a lazy loaded 'client' module, which contains a client-layout component.

Components rendered in `client-layout`, such as the `Home component` load twice, can anyone tell me why this would be?

See the console in slackbitz to see the home component's initialisation message display twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a duplicate `router-outlet`:

client.component.html:

```
<sl-client-layout>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</sl-client-layout>
```

client-layout.component (aka `sl-client-layout`):

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Either change `client.component.html` to:

```
<sl-client-layout></sl-client-layout>
```

or just:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Incredible, client-layout should use content projection not the router. Have replaced with `router-outlet` with `ng-content`. Thanks